# image not loading, jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I load a page with jquery like this:

```
$('#container').load('books/book1/inleiding.php');
```

However, the images are in, books/book1/images so for inleiding.php it's just images/someImage.jpg

And when i load the page then the link to the image stays the same and therefore doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
$.get('books/book1/inleiding.php', function(data) {
     $('#container').html(data);
     alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

But this has the same problem, is there a easy fix?

Comment: What do you mean by loading the image? Are you just echoing html code with img tags from php? Share your PHP code too.

Comment: Yes, use absolute URL-s for your images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

images should be linked directly to the url or to the server root.
If the image is in `books/book1/images/...` then link it to `books/book1/images/...`.

Maybe you can try to change the src with:

```
$.get('books/book1/inleiding.php', function(data) {
    $('#container').html(data);
    $('#container img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'books/book1/'+$(this).attr('src'));
    });
    //alert('Load was performed.');
});
```